# Failed to pull builder image - Redhat Openshift DotNet Core Starter project

Tags: docker, .net-core, openshift, redhat

I am trying to deploy a sample .NET Core application on Redhat OpenShift, but the build fails every time with the message "Failed to pull builder image."

Following are the logs:

```
Cloning "https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore-ex.git " ...
Commit: 1ded43a7b3737ac31e31eee352134fd7c8c0d424 (Update for 2.1 release.)
Author: Tom Deseyn <tom.deseyn@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 28 10:08:30 2018 +0200
Pulling image "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/openshift/dotnet@sha256:d27fa8df1866765695ba0d2bcc74337732eeddffcaf51759fd4d080fc92d6305" ...
pulling image error : Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
error: build error: unable to get docker-registry.default.svc:5000/openshift/dotnet@sha256:d27fa8df1866765695ba0d2bcc74337732eeddffcaf51759fd4d080fc92d6305
```

Please note that the whole build process is automated in Openshift without any inputs from my side. I did not use the CLI tools. Just created a new project with DotNet2.1. Even the github repo link is provided as a sample project by Openshift for DotNetCore.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like docker is not running on the host, you need to start it.